# How to use boost::filesystem::copy_file for copy in ProgramData?

Tags: c++, boost

There is no copying inside ProgramData. In other folders copies correctly. Maybe an access problem?

```
boost::filesystem::path pFr(C:\ProgramData\Manufacturer\Product\MSSQL.mdf);
boost::filesystem::path pTo(C:\ProgramData\Manufacturer\Product\Archive\MSSQL.mdf);

boost::filesystem::copy_file(pFr, pTo, boost::filesystem::copy_option::overwrite_if_exists);
```

Comment: If you don't have permission to move the file it doesn't matter how you try to move it it'll fail

Comment: There is an overloaded version to get the error code. `void copy_file(const path& from, const path& to, copy_option option, system::error_code& ec);`. Refer to [boost's doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#copy_file)